# Why does [-1] not return the last character of the line in a file?

Tags: python

I want to print the last character of string in python reading from the file.

I am calling as `str[-1]` but it is not working as expected.

**t.txt contains**

```
Do not laugh please!        9
    
Are you kidding me?     4
```

My code is

```py
with open('t.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        print(line[-1])
        # break
```

But it is not printing anything.

Comment: Do you want the last character of the entire file or of each line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The last character of every line is a *newline character*. You can [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) it:

```
print(line.strip()[-1])  
# or print(line.rstrip()[-1])
```

Comment: @Amar: Just to make it as clear as possible, the first line of your file is `"Do not laugh please!        9\n"`.

Comment: @alecxe If remove the  `break` giving error. `IndexError: string index out of range` How can we limit it?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks Bro

Comment: @Amar:  Some lines are just `"\n"`.  Doing `"\n".strip()` gives an empty string.  Indexing the last character of an empty string is an index error.  If you are okay with getting an empty string as an answer on blank lines you can change your indexing to a slice:  `line[-1:]`.

Comment: `rstrip` not `strip`, the OP said nothing about removing leading whitespace

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The problem od `Index error ` is that after every line in `.txt` there is an empty line. If remove it. Every thing is fine.

Comment: @Chris_Rands:  That's a distinction without a difference here.  It won't change the answer.  Of course if he wants to preserve trailing spaces he can do `line.strip('\n')`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Documentation link please.

Comment: @Amar Just put it in a `try` `except` block if you have empty lines

Comment: beware of term _newline character_ which is CR+LF on Windows, LF on Unix and Unix-like systems, and CR on Mac OS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 3):

Simple, take the string and clear it's leading and trailing spaces. Then return the last character in your case. Otherwise simply return last character.

```
line=line.strip()
return line[-1]
```

Comment: I just gave explanation, and also what important is that question, I ask first.