# what does this actually do to the variable

Tags: python

I don't know what this code will do to the variable:

```
number= "5"
change = len(number)
number[change -1]
```

What does `[change - 1]` do to the `number` variable?

Comment: NB: `number` is a string.  Therefore, the `change - 1` index should give you the last character of the string, but since your string is only 1 character, it should just give you that character.  BTW if this is a Python script, this won't show anything.  You probably want to `print` that result.  BTW, decent string tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

Comment: It does nothing to it. You index the string (because it's a string, so don't think of it as a number, it's in quotes) and then throws the result of that indexing away

Comment: if you want a better example, change `number` to something longer, say `number = "3.141592653589"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return last character of string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113223/return-last-character-of-string-in-python)

Comment: @rayryeng thank you very much dude,i was totally lost

Answer (score 1):

- `change` equals the number of characters in the string. 1 in this case, but it could be longer or shorter depending on the length of your string.
- the string is essentially a list of characters
- the index of the first item in a list is 0, so the last index would be the length of the list minus 1
- `number[change - 1]` returns the same result as if you had called `number[len(number) - 1]`, so it will equate to the last character in the string (like the last item in the list). In this case it is 5. But as an exmaple, if you changed number to equal `"5a"`, then `number[change - 1]` would equal `a`.

In cases like this I like to use a few prints to help me visualize what is happening step by step.

```
number = "5"
change = len(number)
result = number[change - 1]

print(number)  # output: 5
print(change)  # output: 1
print(result)  # output: 5


# example using a different string
number = "5a"
change = len(number)
result = number[change - 1]

print(number)  # output: 5a
print(change)  # output: 2
print(result)  # output: a
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do anything "to" the number:

```
number= "5"  # string with single character
change = len(number)  # string is of length "1"
number[change -1]  # number[1 - 1] equals number[0] or char at index zero
```

You can put it into the visualiser to see more clearly what is happening
[Python visualiser](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)