# Test if Current Character is Last Character in String (Python)

Tags: python, string, if-statement, character

Currently working on a python script to convert csv to and sql file.  When the csv is generated NULLs are not inputted in to the text file.  Therefore I have to parse through the data and if there are to commas next to each other (Example: ,,) then I know I need to input a null value in between the two.  I'm having problems with testing to see if the last column in a record is null or not.  Currently I hunt for commas, and if I find another right after, it gets set to null but at the end its just a comma and then the string ends.

I have tried looking around on here, most of what I find is similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113223/return-last-character-of-string-in-python).  Which to what I have found is not the solution to the issue at hand.

Take a look at a small code snippet to see how I'm currently doing it (does not work):

```py
for text in line:
    if(text == ',' and line[indexCurrent+1]==None):
        newLine = line[indexCurrent] + '"NULL"' + line[indexCurrent+1]
```

These are my current results:

From this line:

```
2816 ,, "Jeremie Hermiston",, "789-yb-20772",
```

I get this line:

```
2816 ,"NULL", "Jeremie Hermiston","NULL", "789-yb-20772",
```

I want this line:

```
2816 ,"NULL", "Jeremie Hermiston","NULL", "789-yb-20772","NULL"
```

You can also assume that the comma is the last character in the string, there is nothing (not even an empty space) after that final comma.

Comment: Why don't you just split the line and then replace any empty strings with `"NULL"`?

Comment: `[field or '"Null"' for field in line.split(',')]`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Should be `else '"Null"'` to put the explicit qutoes around it.

Comment: It would also be better if you used the `csv` module, so you don't do something wrong if there are commas inside one of the fiels.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `indexCurrent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the result you asked for using the re module.  Is that an option for you?

In two steps for clarity, first we replace all the ',,' with ',"None",', then we replace terminating commas (',$'; the $ is the end of line anchor) with ',"None"'

```
a = '2816 ,, "Jeremie Hermiston",, "789-yb-20772",'
b = re.sub(',,',',"None",',a)
b = re.sub(',$',',"None"',b)
```